# Warnung: parse_ini_file(sprachen/de-DE/Language.info.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]:

Tags: file, parsing, ini

Habe diesen Fehler

Warnung: parse_ini_file(sprachen/de-DE/Language.info.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: Fehler beim Öffnen des Streams: Keine solche Datei oder kein solches Verzeichnis

in dieser Reihe $curConfigFile = parse_ini_file('sprachen/'.$curObj.'/Language.info.ini');

Wo kann da der fehler sein ?